# Physical interpretation of the relation $\dot{x}(t) \rightarrow i \omega \tilde{x}(\omega)$

Tags: fourier-transform

If $x(t)$ is some time-dependent real quantity i can interpret its Fourier Transform $\tilde{x}(t)$ as representing, in a generic sense, the frequency components of $x(t)$. What about the FT of $\dot{x}(t)$? Can this quantity be correlated in some intuitive way to the "motion" $x(t)$ itself?
In other words, is there some intuitive picture explaining the fact that $\dot{x}(t) \longrightarrow  i \omega \tilde{x}(\omega)$? This discussion should, of course, not be limited to functions that depend on time (only).

Comment: In response to your last point: I think there's an important part that you're missing. The question of how to interpret $i\xi \tilde x(\xi)$ where $\xi$ is the Fourier-dual variable of some other variable $\zeta$ depends *strongly* on the interpretation of the 'original' variable $\zeta$. Therefore, it is quite difficult, to say the least, to make a general statement. That being said, I like your first question. +1

Comment: Since you didn't accept an answer yet, can you describe what extra information you need/want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you can represent a function $f$ (of time) as a Fourier transform $\tilde{f}$ already means that you can imagine the function as a superposition of sinusoids. Focus on any one of those sinusoids

$$s(t) \equiv A \sin(\omega t + \phi).$$

The time derivative (i.e. velocity) is

$$\dot{s}(t) = \omega A \cos(\omega t + \phi) . \quad (*)$$

You can see that $s$ and $\dot{s}$ have the same frequency, but are a quarter cycle out of phase and differ in amplitude by a factor of $\omega$. This is precisely the physical meaning of the $i\omega$ factor which shows up in the frequency domain. Representing the sinusoids in the frequency domain as exponentials

$$\exp[i(\omega t + \phi)]$$

you get a quarter circle phase shift by multiplying by $i$ [1]

$$i \exp[i(\omega t + \phi)] = \exp[i(\omega t + \phi + \pi/2)].$$

The $\omega$ part of $i\omega$ is the same $\omega$ as in $(*)$.

In summary, the physical meaning of $i\omega$ is "scale magnitude by $\omega$ and add a quarter cycle phase shift."

[1] This just comes from the fact that $\exp[i\pi/2]=i$.

Comment: This is a neat explanation of where the $i\omega$ factor comes from. I also agree with the interpretation of the $i$ as introducing a phase shift.
However, I was hoping for something more. For example: why the scale magnitude factor $\omega$ has that particular form? is there a way to get a qualitative understanding of the FT of $\dot{x}(t)$ from the graph of $x(t)$?

Comment: Why the scale factor of $\omega$? It's because that comes out when you do a time derivative. The higher the frequency the faster you're going as you cross $x=0$.

Comment: @glance: What further information would be needed to make this answer acceptable?

Comment: I would like to see some intuitive way to relate the graphs of $x(t)$ and the FT of $\dot{x}(t)$, as I said above. Also some more general consideration on these regards. I don't know if this is possible without going too much in particular examples, I'll think about it and update the question when I think of something, or accept this answer if I conclude that there really is nothing more to be said at this level.

Comment: @glance: You're now asking how to relate "graphs", but in the original question you asked how to understand the $i \omega$ factor. So, I think you should make a new question if you want to ask about relating the graphs. For what it's worth, the graphical relation between $x(t)$ and the FT of $x(t)$ is not really easy to describe. Sine waves turn into spikes and vice versa. Adding the time derivative just adds the linear factor $\omega$ and shift $i$.